# Issue with convering UTC time to particluar Time Zone

Tags: c#, .net

I have a time span value 1:00:00

and I converted this to UTC Datetime

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.Add(timeSpan);
```

Then covert this UTC Date Time to (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dateTime, timeZoneInfo);
```

but it returns me DateTime with hours as "21", where I am expecting it should be "20"

because as (UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada) it should be 1:00:00 AM - 5 = 20:00:00

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Since that time-zone is in **Daylight Savings Time**, currently (DateTime.UtcNow), it is an hour different.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only concerned about the server time

```
int dstOffset = 0;

if (System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.UtcNow))
   dstOffset = -1;
```